# Select All check box in DTOptionsBuilder

Tags: angularjs, select, checkbox

I use angularjs and DTOptionsBuilder to show grid table.
I create a Select All check box for the first column (this column show a check box at each row.)

This is HTML source code:

```
<table dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs" datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-res" id="dataTables-res">

<thead>
<tr >
<th style="width: 15px;">
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="checkAllRes()" ng-model="selectedAllRes['checked']" >
<th >
...
<th >
<th translate="TABLE_RE.COMMENTS">Comments</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Source code in control:

```
    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('order', [1 ,"desc"]).withOption('processing', true).withPaginationType('full_numbers');

    $scope.checkAllRes =  function()
    {
    var selectObject  = {};
     if ($scope.selectedAllRes['checked']) {
       angular.forEach($scope.res, function (item) {
             selectObject[item.resId] = true
        });
     }
     $scope.selectedRes =  selectObject ;
    };
```

My problem is:
When I click Select All check box, all row on all pages are checked.
I want:

- Only rows on current page are checked. And, when I click on other page, Select All check box become unchecked.
- When I click old page that I checked Select All check box before, I see all row on this page are checked and Select All check box is checked. (To sum up, I like it work the same as on Google Mail pages.)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you please share a fiddle/plunker to debug? With pagination, this works fine as shown in this plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/PU2ZFEsYPwcWrfgRnCwh?p=preview But coming back to this page doesnt show boxes as checked. If this would help, I can try implementing that as well

Comment: Thank you. Temporarily it's OK not implement the same as google mail. I manipulate on each page only. When user clicks other page, selected item on current page are reset. $scope.dtInstanceCallback = function (dtInstance) {
          dtInstance.DataTable.on('draw.dt', function (value,result) {
              $("#cb_checkall_re").attr('checked', false); // Unchecks it
              var cb_reservations = $(".cb-reservations");
              angular.forEach(cb_reservations, function (item) {
                  $(item).attr('checked', false); // Unchecks it
              });
      });
    };